# Upgrade / Cancel Force.com User License

Tags: force.com, userlicense

My one of the client has subscribed for an Enterprise Edition and purchased 7 Force.com - App subscription user license but now all those user who assigned to this license are unable to access lead and some other standard stuffs. My client did a contract for 3 years.

Is there any way to cancel those user license and upgrade some of them to salesforce license?

Answer (score 1):

Yes is the short answer.  The client needs to work with their Salesforce Account representative and ask that the licenses be upgraded.  You will need to make sure you've created the new profiles that they need and you may need to ask Salesforce to allow both licenses while you do the conversion.  After you are done Salesforce can remove the force.com app licenses.

Comment: My client sales representative is saying that he can not do anything about it!!! :(

Comment: they can, I've worked with clients that have done similar things - If your client is very small it may be why they are resisting.  Has your client tried opening a support ticket? Maybe they could get a different sales person.

Comment: They are pretty easy to work with on upgrading to a full license from Platform. Canceling however is where it gets more complicated. I would make sure that your client is clear in their desired outcome "cancel vs. upgrade" with their sales rep  or customer success manager. Are there other types of users in the org?